# iOS 10: How to repeat local notification once fired on particular date?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a local notification on a specific date and then repeat every 30 seconds AFTER that local notification gets fired off. Here's my code:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ID, content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Another problem: How do I set up multiple alarms to accomplish same result?

Example:

Alarm1: 1/21/2017 @ 8:30am -> repeats every 30 seconds

Alarm2: 1/22/2017 @ 8:32am -> repeats every 30 seconds
...
so on.

What's the best strategy to do this?

Comment: according to https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger   `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)`  may help

Comment: that would repeat every day at 8:30 for example. not every 30 seconds after 8:30am.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to setup two `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`. I am assuming you want to repeat every 30 second when user does not response.

One at `Alarm1: 1/21/2017 @ 8:30:00` that with `repeat: false`. And add a 2nd `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` at `1/21/2017 @ 8:30:30` with `repeat: true`.

You could remove the 2nd `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` when user response to the first notification.

So far, there isn't **one** `UserNotificationTrigger` that allow repeat at different internal without user responding to the notification.

Comment: You answered part of my question. What I want is something similar to Alarmify where once the alarm triggers at - say - 8:30am it keeps repeating forever until the user stops the alarm.